# Add objects from case class in Scala

Tags: scala, class, object, append, case

So, I am new to programming and this might be a very rookie question.
I need to add elements to an object. How is this done?

```
scala>    case class test (
                               a: String,
                               b: String,
                               c: Int,
                               d: Int
                             )





        var teamData_Temp = test(lol, lel,1, 2)

        var teamData_All = teamData_Temp
```

Then let's say that `teamData_Temp` becomes teamData_temp = test(kok,kek,3,4) at some point in the script

How do I produce `teamData_All = (test(lol,lel,1,2),test(kok,kek,3,4))` ???

Answer (score 2):

Scala is a *statically* typed language. This means that although variables declared with `var` can be replaced with a new value, the type of that variable cannot change over the lifetime of the program. The type of `teamData_All` in your script is `test` while the type of `teamData_All` that you are trying to change it to is `Tuple2[test, test]` (or equivalently `(test, test`)). These are incompatible types.

If you want to have `teamData_All` be growable, you have to specify that sort of behavior upfront when declaring the variable, e.g. by making it a list of type `List[test]`. Then you could have one line set `teamData_All = List(test(lol,lel,1,2))` and then have another line set `teamData_All = List(test(lol,lel,1,2),test(kok,kek,3,4))`.

The reason why this is necessary for a statically typed language is because if you make references to `teamData_All` in multiple places in your code, there is no way for the compiler to statically, i.e. before running your code, know what the type of `teamData_All` is at a given point, since you might have changed its type. This makes it impossible for the compiler to make its usual guarantees (e.g. making sure you're only calling methods on things that actually have that method defined).

Comment: If this seems insanely stifling to you (e.g. if your usual programming language of choice is a dynamically typed and imperative one), I can only say give it a couple of days; the same things that seem stifling become very valuable in guiding you as your code gets more complex.